# Цикл For выполнение кода при не совпадении

Tags: javascript

Как выполнить код если не обнаружено совпадений в for к примеру:

```
const arr = [{"name":"Member1"},{"name":"Member2"},{"name":"Member3"},{"name":"Member4"}]
for (let member of arr) {
  if (member.name == "Member5") {
    console.log("Member5 Найден");
  }
}

// Какой-то код...

console.log("Member5 Не найден");
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто. Надо завести булевую переменную **перед циклом**

```
let memberFound = false;
```

Внутри цикла, если что-то нашлось, то поставить `memberFound = true;`

За циклом проверять флаг

```
if (!memberFound) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 0):

Для этого хорошо подходит метод [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), который

> проверяет, удовлетворяет ли какой-либо элемент массива условию,
> заданному в передаваемой функции

```js
const arr = [{"name": "Member1"}, {"name": "Member2"}, {"name": "Member3"}, {"name": "Member4"}]
const element = "Member5"
if (arr.some((member) => member.name === element)) {
    console.log(`${element} найден`)
} else {
    console.log(`${element} НЕ найден`)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое